# Correspondence between addressings of a graph and quadratic forms

Tags: graph-theory, quadratic-forms

In "A course in combinatorics" by Lint and Wilson, 2nd edition, the example on page 78, we have a simple graph (5 vertices)

[image]

with the possible addressing

[image]

To the first column, we associate the product $(x_1 + x_2)(x_4 + x_5)$. Here $x_i$ is the first, respectively second factor, if the address of $x_i$ has a $1$, respectively a $0$, in the first column.
Doing the same for colums, we obtain the quadratic form
$$
\sum d_{ij} x_i x_j
$$
where $d_{ij}$ is the distance between $x_i$ and $x_j$ in $G$.  In matrix notation, $\frac{1}{2}{\bf x}^TA{\bf x}$.

What are the entries of $\bf x$ and $A$, please? I am a beginner in combinatorics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very clear question, but I'll try to answer it.
The entries of the matrix $A$ are $d_{ij}$,
where $d_{ij}$ is the distance between two vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ in our graph.
For the graph in your figure we get
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $\bf x$ is the column of independent variables $x_i$.
Let us denote our quadratic form $f$, that is, $f=\frac{1}{2}{\bf x}^TA{\bf x}$.
We have
\begin{align*}
f&=\frac{1}{2}{\bf x}^TA{\bf x}\\
&=(x_1+x_2)(x_4+x_5)\\
&+x_1(x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5)\\
&+(x_1+x_4)(x_3+x_5)\\
&+x_2(x_3+x_5)\\
&+x_3x_5
\end{align*}
The line with the number $i$ of the last formula corresponds to the $i$th column of your coding table. I strongly recommend that you check this equality. I think you will see that this kind of equality is always true, not only for this particular graph.

**Addition.**
Again ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^T$, where $x_i$ are independent variables. These variables in our case can take arbitrary real values.
Further, $f$ is not a scalar, $f$ is a quadratic form, or a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$, or if you like, a function in $n$ variables $x_i$.

Comment: ....but what is the numeric content of the vector $\mathbf{x}$? In the end, one has to perform a vector-matrix-vector multiplication, to obtain the scalar $f$.

Comment: @AlexanderK. See the addition to the answer.